# Should I use new Type() or just Type() for calling a constructor

Tags: f#, coding-style, constructor

Both syntaxes are equivalent (at least I suppose they are).

```
let o1 = new Object()
```

or

```
let o2 = Object()
```

Which way do you use more often? What about readability issues?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are the same.

I prefer using 'new', with little good reason other than it is what I am accustomed to in other languages, and it makes it easier to findstr/grep for constructor calls (lacking smart tools to 'find all references' in a solution).

Answer (score 18):

I feel like omitting "new" is a bit more functional, so that's my preference.  I like that you can treat a constructor just like any other function returning an instance of a type.

Comment: Would make sense too.. I think the important stuff is to make a choice and then conform to it.

Answer (score 13):

I second what kvb says. Additionally, I omit `new` because this allows me to invoke members directly on the constructed object, just like in C#. For example, the follow code works:

```
DateTime(2012, 12, 21).ToString()
```

The following code *does not* work and results in a compiler error:

```
new DateTime(2012, 12, 21).ToString()
```

So now I need to parenthesize the `new` expression in order to get it to compile:

```
(new DateTime(2012, 12, 21)).ToString()
```

I don't like extra parentheses, so I avoid using `new` now.

The *one case* where I would still use it is when I am creating an object that implements `IDisposable`. This is because if I omit the `new` keyword when creating a `IDisposable` the F# compiler gives a warning:

```
let writeFile =
    let writer = StreamWriter(@"hello.txt")
    writer.WriteLine("hello")
```

Results in this:

> warning FS0760: It is recommended that objects that support the
>   IDisposable interface are created using 'new Type(args)' rather than
>   'Type(args)' to indicate that resources may be owned by the generated
>   value

I can get rid of the warning by adding in the `new` keyword:

```
let writeFile =
    let writer = new StreamWriter("hello.txt")
    writer.WriteLine("hello")
```

The warning also causes me to realize that I should really have a `use` binding for my `IDisposable`:

```
let writeFile =
    use writer = new StreamWriter("hello.txt")
    writer.WriteLine("hello")
```

But if I wrote my code to use `new` *all the time* then I would never get the warning reminding me that I am working with an `IDisposable`!!!

It also makes for less typing. ;-)

Comment: Very logical reasoning as to why not use `new`, but only `use` when necessary. Musing over parenthesis results in clean code.