# When does an F# type need to be initialised using new?

Tags: class, f#, constructor

Given a class such as:

```
type MyClass() =
    member this.Greet(x) = printfn "Hello %s" x
```

is it appropriate to initialize instances using

```
let x = new MyClass()
```

or without the `new`?

Also, when is the use of a `new` constructor more useful than a `do` binding with parameters supplied to the type definition?

Comment: See also duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829665/should-i-use-new-type-or-just-type-for-calling-a-constructor

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My pattern in F#  for using new is to only do so when the type implements `IDisposable`.  The compiler special cases this use and emits a warning if `new` is omitted.

So in your case I would not use `new`.  But with the following I would

```
type OtherClass() =
  ...
  interface System.IDisposable with 
    member this.Dispose() = ...

let x = new OtherClass()
```

Comment: I wonder why this came about. Wouldn't it be clear by using the `use` keyword?

Comment: @ChaosPandion, no idea really.  I'm sure Brian will be along shortly to provide the full history

Comment: @ChaosPandion: there are circumstances where you don't want to create a new IDisposable with a use binding, like when you want it to escape the function that creates it.

Comment: I almost always say `new`.  I think if you have a function with the same name as a class, then you need `new` to disambiguate.  I don't know of any style guideline here.

Comment: @Brian, why does the F# compiler chose to enforce this specific case?

Comment: @Brian: Interesting. The reason I am leaning towards not using `new` is precisely to have the ambiguity between class creation and having a function that returns instances (possibly as a factory). This kind of ambiguity looks to me similar in some sense to the ambiguity profitably used in a name that can be imported from multiple namespaces or modules. Is there anything wrong with that?

Comment: Sure, if you want to do `type Foo() = ...` followed by `let Foo() = new Foo()` as a protective abstraction, that's fine.

Answer (score 4):

F# spec:

> **68
>   6.5.2 Object Construction Expressions** 
>   An expression of the form new ty(e1 ... en) is an object construction expression and constructs a new instance of a type, usually by calling a constructor method on the type.
>
> **14.2.2 Item-Qualified Lookup**
>   The object construction ty(expr) is processed as an object constructor call as if it had been written new ty(expr).

F# compiler issues a warning if instance of type that implements IDisposable is created with Ty() syntax omitting **new** keyword. Spec says nothing about this fact, however I think it should definity should be mentioned.