# When `new` is not optional?

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming

I have to use `new` to create new instances of dynamically created, anonymous object types that are based on existing base types, or interfaces, using object expressions:

```
let a = { new System.Object() with member x.ToString() = "F#" }
```

But in other cases, for example computation expressions, I don't have to write `new` at all:

```
type MaybeBuilder() =
    member this.Bind(x, f) = match x with
                             | None -> None
                             | Some a -> f a
    member this.Return(x) = Some x

let maybe = new MaybeBuilder()
ley maybe2 = MaybeBuilder()
```

I'd like to ask, when is `new` not an optional to write?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When does an F# type need to be initialised using new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398916/when-does-an-f-type-need-to-be-initialised-using-new)

Comment: This is not a duplicate because it involves object expressions - the other answer does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two examples are using completely different language features, even though they use the same `new` keyword.

You are never required to use `new` to call a constructor, as in your second example (in contrast to C# where you must use it).

But in F#, the `new` keyword is also used for the object expression feature, as in your first example. It is needed there because there are different uses for curly braces in F#. The compiler only knows that you are writing an object expression because it sees `{ new`.

Comment: except when calling a constructor of a class that implements `IDisposable`, in which case omitting `new` results in a warning (mentioned in the linked question).