# The value or constructor 'XmlDocument' is not defined

Tags: f#

When I try to instance a xmldocument object in f#, why do I get an error message?

```
open System.Xml
let doc = XmlDocument()
```

The error message is:

> ip.fsx(5,11): error FS0039: The value or constructor 'XmlDocument' is
>   not defined

Before I execute this code, I do

```
> #r "System.Xml";;
--> Referenced 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.Xml.dll'
```

What do I wrong?

Comment: Cannot reproduce your error. Have you tried to reset F# interactive?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try :

```
  let doc = new XmlDocument()
```

Here, *new* is a shorthand for calling a function associated with the type XmlDocument that constructs a value of the given type - these functions are called ***constructors***. Not all F# and .NET types use constructors. (exerpt from Don Syme's book page 21.)

This is the reason that it is sometimes confusing where to put the *new* keyword.

For an explanation on where to use new keyword :

- [msdn ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd233192(v=vs.100).aspx)
- this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520640/f-new-keyword-what-is-it-for)

Comment: You don't need to use `new` keyword

Comment: @Petr : Most F# answers include new keyword ; see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332871/f-xml-parsing  ; also used in Don Syme's "Expert F#" book page 209 of version 2.

Comment: It is misleading. The code from the question is working without `new` keyword

Comment: Yes you may use new keyword to create objects but you don't have to. And it is not the cause of the problem in question.